# ckeditor auto adjust text on font-size change

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts, ckeditor

Is there any way to capture an event when user change font-size?

I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
CKEDITOR.editor.getCommand('font-size').on('change', function(){

});
```

### Problem Description :

I am facing problem when I add text and put it at corner of ckeditor edittable area and then when I change font-size from dropdown it hide means goes out side of area.

### Requirement :

It should be auto adjust according to last position.

### Screenshot for more information :

- [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gi6U.png - default text position (It's ok)
- [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUq88.png - after changing font size (It's not ok)